# Tortoise SVN won't commit, conflict

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I created a conflict by deleting a folder while committing a change to my repository, and now there's a red exclamation point over the folder that won't go away. I've tried committing the folder again, but I get an error:

Commit failed (details follow):
  'W:\LDraw\datsville\svn\trunk\povray\New folder' is scheduled for addition, but
   is missing

How do I set things aright?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Tortoise SVN, right click on the missing file / folder and select `Revert...`
This will revert the changes you made (undelete the folder) so you'll be able to commit other files.
Hope this helps.