# Eclipse svn file scheduled for addition, but is missing

Tags: eclipse, svn

When I try to do a commit in Eclipse svn I get this error: "config-1.0.0.jar.svntmp' is scheduled for addition, but is missing". config-1.0.0.jar is a file in my project, but I don't understand where the svn temp file comes from. I have tried cleaning the project before commiting but I get the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have added the file via "svn add". After that, you deleted the file. Thus, the current "svn commit" cannot succeed because the file is missing. Cleaning does not change anything, because the file is already added. You need to undo the "svn add" manually via "svn rm".

Answer (score 0):

What work for me is **Revert** 
 just Right click on the file which is missing from commit window and Click revert 
 described  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19471165/4741746)